# Making lines on the widgets

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Let's say we have a gridview and I want to draw a solid line on the first and second grid. Then I want to draw a line on the eighth and ninth grid in the same way. I want these two lines to appear at the same time on the screen. I thought I could draw a line to the screen by position with showdialog() as in the example code, but there will need to be more than one line on the screen. In addition, these lines will appear on the screen one after the other, not at the same time. Is there a way you can suggest for this?

```
     showDialog(
              barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
context: context,
barrierDismissible: true,
builder: (BuildContext context) {
return Dialog(
  
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
  surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
  insetPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 60, top: 150),
  child: Container(
    
    width: 50,
      height: 5,
      color: Colors.black,
   
  ),
);
},
);
```

Comment: can you show us an image you wanted to achieved in the UI?

Comment: Actually, I think it's the same logic as the game in the link, but I couldn't see any code examples related to it. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOS_(game))

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Stack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liEGSeD3Zt8) in combination with the [CustomPaint](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kp14Y4uHpHs) class. First, you put your whole Grid into a Stack. In this Stack, you also put your CustomPaint class that draws lines where you want them to be.

Comment: I tried the lines stay behind the grids

Comment: If gridview is placed inside custompaint and custompaint's foregroundPainter property is used, the lines go to the top.